# RegExp for filtering jquery url

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to make Regular Expression to allow matches below.

I'm new on regular expression, i read reference for regexp but still dont know how to make regexp like below.

> jquery-"1~2.1~12.1~10" or "latest".min.js

**Example**

```
jquery-2.2.3.min.js

jquery-latest.min.js

jquery.min.js
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Try `^jquery.*?\.min\.js$`

Comment: @Tushar i dont want to get results of jquery-ui stuffs. so it should filtered with number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only the examples you mentioned above, you could do:

```
jquery(-2\.2\.3|-latest|)\.min\.js
```

If you want whatever begins with jquery and ends with "min.js", then just allow to have any character:

```
jquery(.*)\.min\.js
```

Example of the first regex: https://regex101.com/r/eD7aG9/4

Example of the second regex: https://regex101.com/r/eD7aG9/3

Comment: 2.2.3 was just a example. maybe it filtered with range of number.